# maven archetype: generate a default value for requiredProperty from a value of an existing property

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to set a default value for a requiredProperty in archetype-metadata.xml such that it is based on another property passed from command line. Say

```
<requiredProperty key="customProperty">
        <defaultValue>${artifactId.toUpperCase()}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

However, when I use the resulting archetype to generate a new project, it is not the project's artifactId that gets uppercased, but rather the archetype's artifactId. Whereas when I change it to

```
<requiredProperty key="customProperty">
        <defaultValue>${artifactId}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

I get the project's artifactId as one would expect.

Is there a way to assign a default value for a custom property based on the value of another property?

**Note: this happens only in interactive mode.**

### How to reproduce:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DartifactId=archet -DgroupId=com.example -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-archetype
```

For some reason, archetype.xml gets generated. It is my understanding, it is an old format. Replaced it with archetype-metadata.xml (minimized for the sake of an example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archetype-descriptor name="basic">

    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="customPropertyUppercased">
            <defaultValue>${artifactId.toUpperCase()}</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="customProperty">
            <defaultValue>${artifactId}</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>

        <!--JUnit version to use in generated project-->
        <requiredProperty key="junit-version">
            <defaultValue>4.12</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet filtered="true" packaged="true">
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</archetype-descriptor>
```

A template at `./src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/App.java:`

```
package ${groupId}.${artifactId};

/**

${customPropertyUppercased}

${customProperty}

*/
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Generating a new project using the resulting archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=stacktest -DarchetypeArtifactId=archet -DarchetypeGroupId=com.example -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

with all properties set to default produces `stacktest/src/main/java/com/example/App.java:`

```
package com.example.stacktest;

/**

ARCHET

stacktest

*/
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

So, the customPropertyUppercased is based on the archetype's artifactId, while customProperty is based on the project's artifactId.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Make sure you're using the latest Maven Archetype Version (2.4).

Comment: @Tunaki: done, sorry for ambiguity in the question.

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce that. Just made a small project with your set-up. Did you update your local catalog after the modifications? Make sure your root POM (the POM of the archetype project) is [according to this page](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-packaging/) and that you run `mvn clean install` on it.

Comment: @Tunaki: I have updated the pom.xml to as the page you've mentioned suggests. I've run `mvn clean install archetype:update-local-catalog`. The result is the same, though.

Comment: Hm well we're entering the "works for me" scenario :). I don't see a reason why this would use the wrong artifact id. At this point... maybe you can make a GitHub repo with the issue?

Comment: @Tunaki: https://github.com/badbishop/maven_archetype_creation_test I've created it manually once again, tested locally with same weird result.

Comment: I get the same error, but only in interactive mode. With the -B parameter to maven, it works as expected.

Comment: @HaraldKorneliussen: thank you, me too. The question has been updated.

Comment: Ah interactive mode is the culprit indeed. You had `mvn -B` in your steps to reproduce, that is why I didn't see it. Well, in interactive mode, you can input what you want, but you're right that it defaults to the archetype artifact id. Looks like a bug, you may want to raise a JIRA issue here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in the archetype plugin, and is documented here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-490